# how to scroll animate of div view to specific x and y coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to scroll animate of div view to specific x and y coordinates.

```
this.onClickButtonArrows1 = function ( element, scrollDirection )
    {
        if( scrollDirection == "down")
        {

            var element1 = document.getElementById('shape_74');
            var position = element1.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x_pos = position.left;
            var y_pos = position.top;

            $(element).animate({ top: y_pos+'px', left: x_pos+'px' }, 1000);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) function:

```js
...

window.scrollTo({
  top: y_pos,
  left: x_pos,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Comment: thanks. this will scroll to specific x and y coordinates of an element.

Answer (score 1):

Use **scrollIntoView()**

```
var element = document.getElementById("box"); 
element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth", 
      block: "end", 
      inline: "nearest"
});
```